# How do you increase the size of an image without increasing size of the background

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi All I have an image with background. I want to increase the size of only the image whilst the background size remains the same. when I use `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w, h))`, it increases both the image and background by the same ratio. Is there a way to freeze the background size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [subplot_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) seems like the easiest way to do this, just put 0 in the arguments, or negative values.

Comment: try a `constrained` or `tight` layout: `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w, h), layout='constrained')`